# gammu.ERR_TIMEOUT - Raspberry pi

Tags: python, exception, raspberry-pi, gammu

Good afternoon!

I have a problem and do not know how I can solve it.

I am using gammu and did my python code and I'm using the raspberry pi, so far so good! 
The problem is that after some time the gammu emits the error gammu.ERR_TIMEOUT. or sometimes this error gammu error opening device

This is what I did so far

I saw the settings to see if the modem port was correct 
  then reconnected the modem 
I've been searching on the site for gammu exceptions to see what could be the error

my biggest problem is that this happens often randomly

ok it identifies the modem but gammu.ERR_DEVICEOPENERROR gives the error: { 'Text' : u'Error opening device . Unknown, busy or no permissions' , ' Code . ' : 2 , ' Where ' , ' init '}
[image: this is the error]

Answer (score 1):

Quite late answer, but maybe still useful:

I'm also using a Raspberry Pi with 3G USB modem and python-gammu. From my experience, different 3G modems behave very differently: with one of them (ZTE MF190), my python script (polling for incoming SMS once per minute) happily interacts with for weeks without any problems. With another one (Huawei E1820) I'm getting timeout errors several times every day during a few minutes up to hours.

Make sure that not two of your processes are trying to interact with the modem at the same time - that was one of the problems I had that caused some of these errors. Otherwise in my case restarting the RPi whenever that exception occurs is the acceptable workaround.